# Генерация неприводимого полинома над конечным полем

Tags: криптография

Тема моей курсовой работы рюкзачная криптосистема Хора-Ривеста. В ходе работы нужно сгенерировать случайный нормированный неприводимый полином. Я реализовал библиотеку для работы с полиномами и написал генерацию неприводимых полиномов по алгоритму из книги "Handbook of Applied Cryptography".

[image: generating algorithm]

Один из пунктов в тестировании полинома на неприводимость 2.2 это вычисление НОД от `f(x)` и `u(x) - x`. В программе часто получается так, что `u(x) = x`, и в НОД передается `u(x) - x = 0`, что приводит к ошибке, так как туда не могут передаваться нулевые полиномы. В чем может быть проблема? Мне кажется что такая ситуация вполне реальна, но как с ней бороться? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Необязательно же проверять в лоб. [Вот список тестов многочленов на неприводимость в конечных полях.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/methods-to-see-if-a-polynomial-is-irreducible) [Или вот еще теорема основанная на простых числах.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn's_irreducibility_criterion) Правда сомневаюсь что алгоритм на её основании будет иметь пригодную сложность.